# How can i abort a jenkins job if no changes are checked in a worskpace project during the build

Tags: jenkins, tfs

i'm using Jenkins with TFS (Team Foundation Server) and SonarQube, I configured a job to be launched periodically to import the project from TFS and analyse it in SonarQube, but I search how can I abort the build and don't do the code analysis if no changes are detected by this job in a project workspace compared to the last build

Answer (score 0):

This should be handled not *after* checkout, but before. Do this in the setup of the SCM portion of your Jenkins job. It looks like you should use polling to limit job execution to only when there are changes.

Comment: i don't find this option, can you give a screenshot please ?

Comment: No such options, you may need to write script to compare the changes first, then do corresponding actions accordingly.